# Using dependency property in wpf in this practical example

Tags: .net, wpf

I want to use dependency property which will represent `ICarRepository` instance.

So I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802278/how-do-you-pass-parameters-from-xaml) and based on acc. answer I tried with my example

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty RepositoryProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    null,
    typeof(ICarRepository ),
    typeof(TreassureControl),
    **new PropertyMetadata(??????)** what to put here?
    );

    public ICarRepository Repository
    {
       get { return (ICarRepository)GetValue(RepositoryProperty); }
       set { SetValue(RepositoryProperty, value); }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PropertyIdentifier` cannot be null (first parameter), pass CLR wrapper property name in it which is `Repository`.

Regarding `PropertyMetadata`, you can set that to `null`. Also you can use other overload where you don't need to pass that value.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RepositoryProperty = 
 DependencyProperty.Register(
       "Repository",
        typeof(ICarRepository ),
        typeof(TreassureControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

OR simply avoid last parameter:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RepositoryProperty = 
 DependencyProperty.Register(
       "Repository",
        typeof(ICarRepository ),
        typeof(TreassureControl));
```

Comment: Can you be more clear by `example of receiving ICarRepository instance trough xaml`? Where you want to bind that?